# About solving the second order difference equation: $x_{n+1}= (1+1/r^{2n+1})x_{n}-x_{n-1}/r^{2n+1}+2/r^{(n+1)^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $r>4$ be a positive integer. I wante to solve this second order difference equation: $$x_{n+1}= (1+1/r^{2n+1})x_{n}-x_{n-1}/r^{2n+1}+2/r^{(n+1)^{2}}$$ with respect to $x_{n}$.

I am not able to find the good idea.

Comment: Is x a function of r or is r just a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your equation as
$$x_{n+1}-x_n= \frac{1}{r^{2n+1}}(x_{n}-x_{n-1})+2/r^{(n+1)^{2}}$$ 
which is equivalent to
$$r^{(n+1)^2}(x_{n+1}-x_n)= r^{n^2}(x_{n}-x_{n-1})+2.$$ 
Letting $u_n=r^{n^2}(x_{n}-x_{n-1})$, you will have
$$ u_{n+1}-u_n=2. $$
It is very easy to solve.